# TabLayout only shows one tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I've tab layout in my app , this is my code :

```
 tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab().setText("ss");
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);
    tab = tabLayout.newTab().setText("qq");
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);
    tab = tabLayout.newTab().setText("zz");
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);
    tab = tabLayout.newTab().setText("ww");
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);
```

this is my layout code :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabContentStart="72dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_services" />
```

the problem is, when I launch my application, it only shows one tab and it doesn't show the others , I don't know why.

Comment: can you post you viewpager adapter code here?

Comment: @Raja thanks for reply , I don't have viewpager adapter, I just make tabs

Comment: see my post it will help you... now i tried its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You're adding multiple time the same TabLayout.Tab, that is being "overwritten"

Do like this:

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab().setText("ss");
tabLayout.addTab(tab);
TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("qq");
tabLayout.addTab(tab2);
TabLayout.Tab tab3 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("zz");
tabLayout.addTab(tab3);
TabLayout.Tab tab4 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("ww");
tabLayout.addTab(tab4);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , I just do that but it doesn't make any different

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("ss"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("qq"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("zz"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("ww"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this line in your xml

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_services"
```

it will work fine

Comment: now i have to try with your code its working fine without the above mentioned line